# Can some someone explain me scope of property this.Hash

Tags: javascript, scope

I don't understood why when I make call like this     new _AutoInit(); console.log(_pear()); I got undefined  but when I make call like this  _AutoInit(); console.log(_pear()); I got ?

```
var _AutoInit = function()
{

    this.Hash = '?';
};
var _pear = function() {
        return this.Hash;
};
 new _AutoInit();
 console.log(_pear())
///////////////////////////
_AutoInit();
console.log(_pear());
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `new`, the `this` inside `_AutoInit` is `window`, so you've done

```
window.Hash = '?';
```

Now in `_pear`, the `this` here is `window` (or *undefined*), so

```
return window.Hash; // returns "?"
```

And logging it logs `?`

---

You probably wanted to set up inheritance, so something like this

```
var _AutoInit = function () {
    this.Hash = '?';
};
_AutoInit.prototype._pear = function () {
        return this.Hash;
};
// then
var a = new _AutoInit();
a._pear(); // "?"
```